# Density of a countable union of rational lines

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $Y$ be the set formed by the union of all the straight lines (in the plane) going through the point $(0, 0)$, and with a slope given by a rational number.  Is $S$ **dense** in $\mathbb{R}^2$? (Let's call the lines in $S$ "rational lines".)
>   If so, then is the set consisting of the rational points of $S$ (points with rational coordinates), say $S'$, also **dense** in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which would imply that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is **separable**?

(We assume the Euclidean metric.)

---

I see no reason why this would not be the case.  That is, any open ball in the plane is traversed by countably many rational lines, and so any open ball contains countably many rational points.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes. Also, observe that the set $S'$ is essentially $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something tricky in the wording, both are true, although there are simpler ways of showing that ${\mathbb R}^2$ is separable (e.g. use points such that both coordinates are rational). However, how difficult it is to prove these statements will depend on what you can assume and what level of mathematical detail is needed.

Comment: *any open ball in the plane is traversed by countably many rational lines* --- This statement, however, seems pretty much irrelevant to me. More relevant is the fact that any (nonempty) open ball in the plane is traversed by at least one of these rational lines (for density considerations). For countability, there are countably many of the rational lines and each of these countably many rational lines contains countably many rational points, so even if we count the rational points separately (i.e. assume they're all distinct, which they aren't), we get countably many of the rational points.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you both. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and Yes. Let $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $(u,v)\in(\Bbb Q-\{0\})\times\Bbb Q$ such that $|a-u|,|b-v|<\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ so that $(u,v)$ is a rational point on the rational line $L:y=(\frac{v}{u})x\subset Y$ and $$\sqrt{(a-u)^2+(b-v)^2}<\epsilon$$